# Json parsing with arduino uno

Tags: json, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to parse json response from a server.

I'm using arduino uno with a wifi shield. Also is it advisable to process json? I read that the uno may have too little memory for this.

Comment: You will get better answers quicker asking at [the Arduino stack exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are communicating with you wifi shield via USART. So you read characters/Strings. Why shouldn't you be able to parse them any way you like? Depending on how trivial your json is you could roll your own parser or have a look at [ajson](http://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/ajson-arduino-json-library/).

Memory should not be a problem as long as your json documents are relatively small (< ~1k).

Comment: Do you have a simple example of arduino parsing a json response efficiently? Thanks

Comment: What efficiency means will depend on your use case. Like @LeeAllan, I suggest you look at the Arduino stackexchange. See for example [here](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/parse-json-with-arduino-to-turn-on-led).